# Getting a Nested Json with http request returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json api that I'm trying to GET. However, the nested "studentInscription" value is always null. Other values are fetched correctly and can be accessed.

```
[
  {
    "studentId": 10,
    "studentName": "John Doe",
    "studentInscription": {
      "inscriptionId": 15,
      "inscriptionPrice": 905.25
    }
  },
  {
    "studentId": 12,
    "studentName": "Steve Doe",
    "studentInscription": {
      "inscriptionId": 18,
      "inscriptionPrice": 905.25
    }
  }
]
```

Here's the GET code:

```
Future<List<Student>> getStudents() async {
    try {
      Response res = await get(apiURL);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successfull get request
        List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);
        List<Student> students = body
            .map(
              (dynamic item) => Student.fromJson(item),
            )
            .toList();
        return students;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Could not fetch");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The Student model is as follows:

```
import '.../inscription.dart';

class Student{
  int id;
  String name;
  Inscription inscription;

  Student({this.id, this.name, this.inscription});
 
  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Student(
      id: json['studentId'] as int,
      name: json['studentName'],
      inscription: json['studentInscription'] as Inscription,           // null data
      // inscription: Inscription.fromJson(json['studentInscription']), // tried this but no luck
    );
  }
}
```

The Inscription model is as follows:

```
class Inscription {
  int id;
  double price;

  Inscription({this.id, this.price});

  factory Inscription.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Inscription(
      id: json['inscriptionId'] as int,
      price: json['inscriptionPrice'] as double,
    );
  }
}
```

I ultimately want to be able to do this:

> myList[0].inscription.price

I can do this without issues:

> myList[0].studentName

EDIT, here's the code where I'm using the request:

```
Future<List<Student>> futureStudents = getStudents();

return Container(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: futureStudents,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        print(snapshot.data[0].name); // This has a value
        print(snapshot.data[0].inscription); // This is null
        return _buildListView(snapshot.data);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed out the constructor for `Student` class. 
Try something like this,

```
class Student{
  int id;
  String name;
  Inscription inscription;
 
  // Constructor
  Student({this.id, this.name, this.inscription});
  
  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Student(
      id: json['studentId'],
      name: json['studentName'],
      inscription: Inscription.fromJson(json['studentInscription']),            
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that works!

Comment: I've missed it in the question but it's there

Comment: print(myStudents.list[0]), this gives => "Instance of Student"

Comment: Done, _buildListView is just a custom listView that displays the names

Comment: `Inscription.fromJson(json['studentInscription'])` works for me!